# How can oke calculate $(U_n)$ in function of n

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $S_n=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$

Where $S_n=U_0+U_1+...+U_n$

First we show that $S_n$ is natural, then we can use induction.

But how can one calculate $U_n$ in function of $n$ ?

Comment: Nice question. (+1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $$S_n = \sum_{n = 0}^{n} U_n,$$ we have $$U_n = S_n - S_{n - 1} = \frac {n (n + 1) (2n + 1)} {6} - \frac {n (n - 1) (2n - 1)} {6} = n^2.$$ Hence, $U_n = n^2$.

Answer (score 0):

Show by induction that $U_n=n^2$ for all $n$

Answer (score 0):

Try to compute $S_{n+1}-S_n$. On the other hand, expand this difference with respect to $U_{n+1}$.

Answer (score 0):

Calculate $\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}-\frac{(n-1)((n-1)+1)(2(n-1)+1)}{6}$

$$\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}-\frac{(n-1)(n(2n-1)}{6}$$
$$\frac{n}{6}((n+1)(2n+1)-(n-1)((2n-1)$$
$$\frac{n}{6}(2n^2+3n+1-(2n^2-3n+1)$$
$$\frac{n}{6}(6n)=n^2$$

Therefore $S_n=0^2+1^2+...+(n-1)^2+n^2$